# Unable to upload image converted into byte array in Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an android app in which I need to upload images into Facebook.
I was able to upload photo using a URL but I need to upload photos that a user selects from his device.
Here is my code.

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... param) {

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
       // params.putString("url", "http://famouslogos.net/images/android-logo.jpg");
        params.putByteArray("picture",imageByteArray);
        Log.d("response++/byteArray", imageByteArray.toString());
        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/me/photos",
                params,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        JSONObject jo = response.getJSONObject();
                        try {

                            Log.d("response++\id", response.toString());
                            pid = jo.get("id").toString();
                            Log.d("response++/id", pid);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: So, Wat is your problem ? Any error log ?

Comment: The photo is just not uploading. There is no exception. Nothing.

Comment: Does the facebook API expect a byte array?

Comment: You forgot to explain your code. Please do. How does it work? And show what facebook told you how to do it.

Comment: `Log.d("response++/byteArray", imageByteArray.toString());`. So what is logged there? What usefull info do you get with it?